# Tool to create a bad physical location report on disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-disk, ntfs, ext3

I am in need of a tool that would run on an Ubuntu system that would be able to report the following:

1. Bad physical locations on a disk (cylinders, sectors)
2. Files that are affected by these bad locations.

Filesystem I currently have is NTFS but it would be good to have for ext2/3/4 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't work nowadays. Modern disks "hide" bad blocks (even the most carefully manufactured new disks have them, they are unavoidable with current data densites) by remapping them to spares. You'll "see" bad blocks only when the disk runs out of spares, and in my experience that means that 99% of the time the disk has hours (at best) left before joining the big RAID in the sky.

Comment: Would be nice to get my data off it.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is `badblocks`.  Here's a good article on it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/badblocks